# Angularjs typeahead name undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am getting undefined when the result is returned, can anyone help me out here? I know there's a similar question out there but i couldn't understand the solution. Thus, asking again.

JS:

```
 $scope.cnames = CombinedName;
 console.log($scope.cnames)
```

Console log view :

[image]

Lastly, my html code :

```
      <input type="text" ng-model="selected" uib-typeahead="NAME 
     for cname in cnames | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8">
```

View im getting :

[image]

Comment: what is undefined ?

Comment: Updated @Sajeetharan

Comment: There isn't a `NAME` property on each `cname`, because each `cname` is a string. Try something like `cname for cname in cnames` instead.

Comment: bear in mind, because `cnames` is an array of strings, `selected` will be the index of the element in the array, rather than the text itself.  if you want the text, then `cname as cname for cname in cnames` would probably work.

Comment: wow, that just did the trick. Thanks a million times @Claies!!

Comment: Noted @Claeies. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can just just bind it as ,

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="cname for cname in cnames | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/AzCs59HFn2m22ovh7URh?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

Because the `cnames` array you are working with is a string, you have to use a specific form when iterating through the array.  In general, `ng-options` / `uib-typeahead` expect the array you are iterating to be an array of objects.

When working with an array of strings, you can use

```
cname for cname in cnames
```

to correctly assign the text of the dropdown to the text of the array element.  This will set the `selected` value to the index of the selected element from the source array.

```
cname as cname for cname in cnames
```

would set the `selected` value as the text itself.

all the possible forms are documented at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions.  These are the same forms that are used by UI-Bootstrap.